# существует ли слово "читабельно"?

Tags: словарь, слова

Недавно мой ответ был [отредактирован](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/845012/2) заменой "читабельно" на "читаемо" и комментарием, что слова "читабельно" не существует. Тем не менее [яндекс](https://translate.yandex.ru/?lang=ru-en&text=%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE) (и гугл) понимают его и предлагают корректный перевод.
В [лингво онлайн](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/ru-en/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) оно присутствует в виде прилагательного, а в виде наречия встречается только в примерах из текстов ("читабельнее").

На мой взгляд, использование именно этого слова, а не предложенного аналога более точно отражает суть в данном контексте:

> пишите код так что бы было читабельно

Можно ли считать, что слово существует на основании того, что оно присутствует в базе онлайн словарей? или есть какие то более строгие критерии?

Comment: Слово разговорное и применять его в инструкциях неуместно. Разве нельзя заменить на «чтобы легко читалось»?

Comment: @V.V. так это не инструкция, это пост в Интернете

Comment: Грамматически повелительное наклонение передает приказы, инструкции, советы и рекомендации.

Comment: ОК, раз в инструкциях неуместно, пускай это будет совет или рекомендация

Comment: *Пожалуйста, пользуйтесь кнопкой "share" (она же "поделиться") когда даете ссылку на вопрос. А то полная форма ссылки занимает слишком много места, да и URL-кодирование русских букв выглядит некрасиво.*

Comment: Но спасибо что стали разбираться в вопросе, теперь и я узнал что-то новое...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, факт фиксации слова [в авторитетных словарях](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1088802) является железным подтверждением факта его существования.

Это по поводу незафиксированных слов могут быть споры.

Другое дело, что оно может быть уместно не во всех контекстах, если  оно относится, например, к разговорной лексике, к каковой согласно словарям относится слово `читабельный`.

Но общение в Интернете лично я таким контекстом не считаю, тем более не считаю справедливым редактирование с обоснованием, которое противоречит объективной реальности.

Единственный более строгий, хоть и абсурдный, критерий, который мне приходит на ум, это законодательное закрепление факта существования слова.

В моём восприятии слово `читаемый` лишено значения `удобный для чтения, разборчивый`, и уже только на этом основании я бы отверг его в качестве замены.

Разница между ними уже обсуждалась [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431317/%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%95%D0%9C%D0%AB%D0%99-%D0%B8-%D0%A7%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%91%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%99-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Comment: Есть слово "легкочитаемый", КМК. Но "читаемый" это в самом деле не про удобство а либо про текущую секунду, либо про общеизвестность

Comment: @Arioch хорошее слово, хотя у меня оно больше связывается со складностью изложения материала как атрибутом стиля, чем с его удобством для чтения и разборчивостью как следствием организации текста

Comment: тогда "легкоусвояемый" - и конкурс среди иностранцев по произношению и угадыванию ударения :-) P.S. "со складностью изложения материала как атрибутом стиля" - это для развлекательной литературы. Для справочной литературы понятие и критерии "лёгкости" несколько другие :-D

Comment: @Arioch есть ещё хорошее слово - "удобочитаемый"

Comment: а теперь объясняй иностранцам куда съелся суффикс "н" :-D

Answer (score 0):

Слова `читабельный`, `читабельность` широко употребляются в книгах по программированию. Что такое "слова не существует"? Если оно широко употребляется в книгах по определённой тематике, и известно любому, кто этой тематикой занимается, то оно существует.

Comment: в принципе слово - уродливый англицизм. Было нормальное (пусть и длиннее) слово "легкочитаемый". Но - среди программеров как без англицизмов ?

Comment: @Arioch - Это уж точно не англицизм, иначе оно бы звучало как «читэйбельный» или как-то так. На самом деле это скорее галицизм, гибрид русского корня и французского суффикса.

Comment: Галлицизм в самом конце 20 века? Едва ли... Мы же говорим "фешенебельный", не "фяшенейблиный" @yellowSky

Comment: @Arioch - Если слово короче русского аналога, то это не уродливый англицизм, а красивый англицизм (или красивый галлицизм). Уродливый англицизм - это, например, лакшери вместо роскошь. А слово "принцип", которое вы употребили, тоже, по-вашему, уродливый галлицизм?

Comment: из уродливых англицизмов - ресепшен, ресепшионистка

Comment: И прайслист вместо родного русского "прейскуранта цен" :)))) Слово "принцип" вросло в р.я., а как было на момент его появления в русском языке - не знаю. Например у слова "компьютер" нет "родных" аналогов, были ли они тогда у "принципа" - не вем. Опять же там вроде нет явно чуждых звукосочетаний. ЦЫПленок, ПРИчина, солНЦЕ...

Comment: @Arioch у компьютера положительно есть родной аналог - ЭВМ, в котором два иностранных слова из трёх

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка тогда уж ЦВМ. Но как обычно и бывает с аббревиатурами, она плохо склоняется и вообще несколько чужеродна для языка. Вот "сателлит" в язык не вошел, за исключением узкого дипломатического смысла. А калькулятор вошел, хотя означает буквально то же, что и компьютер :)

Comment: @Arioch ну почему плохо склоняется? эвээма, эвээму, эвээмом, эвээме, а можно вообще не склонять

Comment: Языку же все равно, откуда корень пришёл, была бы обвязка. В НГМД и НЖМД иностранное слово одно - диск. Но в обиходе пользуются "дисководом" (даже "флопповодом") и винчестером. А НЖМДой трудно: без ера даже хлеб невкусный.

Comment: @Arioch почему самый конец века? Слово *читабельный* встречается в печати с 1920х, хотя и редко.

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли его в 1990-х воскресили из ностальгии по "ленинскому неиспорченному коммунизму", мне кажется это новый импорт, независимый. Возможно, вместе с вернувшимися эмигрантами. Но даже если и 1920-е, то тогда в основном технологии импортировали из США и Германии. Т.е. французское влияние на язык в 1920-е - тоже под вопросом.